# Update of records in two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

In airline domain, we have a requirement where we need to update ALLIANCE_FLG to "Y" in the "ALL_TICKETS" table if any of the user's ticket has oneworld or star alliance flag on his ticket ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y' OR if oneworld flag is ONE in "ALL_USERS" table ONEWRLD = "Y".

"ALL_TICKETS" TABLE gets updated as part of everyday batch job. Apart from that, we need to update all the data records that belong to the user if ALLIANCE_FLG = "Y" if any of his previous ticket column does not have any value in that column.

Below are the schema details and the update statement which I used and it is throwing error. Below is the SQL fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/80006/3

Also, "ALL_TICKETS" table and "ALL_USERS" have millions of records. So, is there an optimal query / script using bulk collect update to traverse through those millions of records and update the FLAG accordingly ?

Updating of ALLIANCE_FLG

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data **as part of the question** (not hidden in a fiddle behind a link); and the expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE ... FROM ...` is not valid Oracle syntax. An `UPDATE` statement has `SET` and `WHERE` clauses, not a `FROM` clause.

There is no point updating `ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y'` when the `ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y'` in the same row because you won't change anything so you can ignore that part of your query and instead focus only on the `ALL_USERS` part and, for that, you need to correlate between the two tables (your query does not do any correlation but we can assume you want to correlate on `ALL_TICKETS.USR_ROW_ID = ALL_USERS.ROW_ID`):

```sql
UPDATE ALL_TICKETS T
SET    ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y'
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM   all_users u
              WHERE  u.ONEWRLD = 'Y'
              AND    u.row_id = t.usr_row_id);
```

If you want to update where there is a different row in `ALL_TICKETS` for the same `usr_row_id` with `alliance_flg = 'Y'` then you can correlate the table to itself in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
UPDATE ALL_TICKETS T
SET    ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y'
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM   all_users u
              WHERE  u.ONEWRLD = 'Y'
              AND    u.row_id = t.usr_row_id)
OR     EXISTS(SELECT 1
              FROM   all_tickets at
              WHERE  at.alliance_flg = 'Y'
              AND    at.usr_row_id = t.usr_row_id);
```

You could also implement it as a `MERGE` statement (correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column, which is effectively a direct pointer to a row):

```sql
MERGE INTO all_tickets dst
USING (
  SELECT t.ROWID AS rid,
         MAX(alliance_flg) OVER (PARTITION BY usr_row_id) AS max_alliance_flg,
         u.onewrld
  FROM   all_tickets t
         LEFT OUTER JOIN all_users u
         ON t.usr_row_id = u.row_id AND u.onewrld = 'Y'
) src
ON (   src.rid = dst.ROWID
   AND (src.max_alliance_flg = 'Y' OR src.onewrld = 'Y')
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET   alliance_flg = 'Y'
  WHERE alliance_flg IS NULL OR alliance_flg != 'Y';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tQGtaX4B)

---

> So, is there an optimal query / script using bulk collect update to traverse through those millions of records and update the FLAG accordingly?

You do not want to use PL/SQL and context-switch between the SQL and PL/SQL scopes performing updates on different rows as that will be very inefficient. Just do it all in a single SQL statement and don't use PL/SQL at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ALL_TICKETS at
SET at.ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y'
WHERE at.ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y' OR EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ALL_USERS au
    WHERE au.ROW_ID = at.USR_ROW_ID AND au.ONEWRLD = 'Y'
);
```

This should be a relatively fast query to execute by the database, ofcourse a lot depends on the machine dimensions though.