# Updating ALLIANCE_FLG for all the tickets of one particular user based on conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a requirement where we need to update ALLIANCE_FLG to "Y" for all the airlines tickets that belong to one user in the "ALL_TICKETS" table and user table "ALL_USERS" in oracle database.

The condition is that if any of the flag is 'Y' in any of these columns, then we need to update ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y' in all of his existing airline tickets.

Below are few conditions.

1. If the ONEWRLD = 'Y' at client level (in ALL_USERS table) OR ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y' (ALL_TICKETS table) on user's 1st ticket OR USR_VIP IS NULL (ALL_TICKETS table)  OR ALLIANCE_FLG = 'N' (ALL_TICKETS table)user's 2nd ticket : Then we need to update ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y' on all of the user's tickets
2. If the ONEWRLD IS NULL at client level (in ALL_USERS table) OR ALLIANCE_FLG = 'N' (ALL_TICKETS table) on user's 1st ticket OR USR_VIP IS NULL (ALL_TICKETS table)  OR ALLIANCE_FLG = 'N' (ALL_TICKETS table)user's 2nd ticket : Then we need to update ALLIANCE_FLG = 'N' on all of the user's tickets
3. If the ONEWRLD IS NULL at client level (in ALL_USERS table) OR ALLIANCE_FLG = 'N' (ALL_TICKETS table) on user's 1st ticket OR ALLIANCE_FLG = 'N' (ALL_TICKETS table) on user's 2nd ticket OR ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y' (ALL_TICKETS table) on user's 3rd ticket OR USR_VIP IS NULL (ALL_TICKETS table) : Then we need to update ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y' on all of the user's tickets

Below are the schema details and the update statement which I used and it is throwing error. Below is the SQL fiddle.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f91c/2

Also, "ALL_TICKETS" table and "ALL_USERS" have millions of records. So, is there an optimal query / script using bulk collect update to traverse through those millions of records and update the FLAG accordingly ?

Updating ALLIANCE_FLG for all the tickets of one particular user based on conditions.

Comment: Please update your question with your SQL and the error message, as editable text - dbfiddles are a nice to have but your question still needs to be self contained. Is this actually for 1 user as you don’t seem to have any filter condition for that? You should also be using ANSI SQL join syntax as the join syntax you are using has been outdated for 30+ years. Also you don’t seem to have a condition on your “join” so you’re generating a cartesian product, which is unlikely to be what you want

Comment: You [asked something very similar before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77536798/1509264) and were told that "`UPDATE ... FROM ...` is not valid Oracle syntax." Why are you asking another question with a similar problem where you are using the same invalid syntax?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements (as part of the question, not hidden in a fiddle); **YOUR** attempt at a solution (again, as part of the question); the details of the issues/errors with your query (again, as part of the query and not just a non-constructive statement that "it is throwing an error" but does not tell us what the error is); **AND** the expected output for your query.

Comment: SQL record sets (in all dialects, not just Oracle) are unordered unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause so when you talk about the user's 1st, 2nd or 3rd ticket then unless you specify how to order those rows then there can be no concept of which row is 1st, 2nd or 3rd because they are unordered (and your sample data does not have a column that could be used to order the columns).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update of records in two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536798/update-of-records-in-two-different-tables)

Answer (score 0):

You could use MERGE INTO :

```sql
MERGE INTO ALL_TICKETS t
USING ( Select at.*, au.ONEWRLD
        From ALL_TICKETS at
        Inner Join ALL_USERS au ON(SubStr(au.ROW_ID, 1, Length(au.ROW_ID) - 1) = at.USR_ROW_ID)
        Where at.ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y' OR au.ONEWRLD = 'Y' OR at.USR_VIP = 'Y'
       ) x ON(x.ROW_ID = t.ROW_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET t.ALLIANCE_FLG = 'Y'
```

```sql
5 rows updated.
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM ALL_TICKETS

/*
ROW_ID     TICKET_NUM     ALLIANCE_F USR_VIP    USR_ROW_ID
---------- -------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1-3EWR     TBYJUY         Y          Y          1-4TF     
1-54TR     GVDYRT         Y                     1-4TF     
1-GDV      MTMBZA         Y          N          1-4TF     
1-HYJB     VSKPSLO        Y          Y          1-4TF     
1-NGPJ     LTTCSTM        Y          N          1-L3EF    
1-HYBM     VSKPSLO                              1-L3EF    */
```

NOTE: This is just an example how to use MERGE INTO based on conditions that you put in the fiddle. That is - I didn't have time to analyze the description of conditions from the question as it says '*just a few conditions*'.